# Migration from .gdb to .mdb - how to change automaticly all querys at MXD from " " to [ ]?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, definition-query

after migration from File Geodatabase (.gdb) to Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) - how to change automatically all field names at query definitions at the MXD from " " to [ ]

What's else is important when conducting such transition ? I'm using version 10.1 sp1 and I have a MXD with dozens layers and dozens of queries, also at the symbol classes of the labels there are even more SQL syntax to change.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many such modifications to Definition Queries do you need to make? Are you using ArcGIS 10.1 or 10.2?  Are you comfortable with ArcPy and Python?  Please edit your question to provide any answers rather than as Comments so that potential answerers can read all the relevant info in one place.

Comment: I'm curious about the direction of your migration and what requirements drove that to be your choice.  Using 10.1 SP1 is good because it would let you use arcpy.da.Walk if you later needed to do this in multiple folders.

Comment: The FGDB was the draft and contained the raw material of project and the volume was above 2G. the final version of the project is at PGDB, another reason to migration is to handle fields order using MS ACCESS. I'm new in Python Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: It should be noted that the size limit for PGDBs is 2GB, and that their performance degrades after 500mb.  I'm not certain if you can reorder fields in access without potentially damaging the ArcGIS handling of the feature classes.

Comment: about reordering fields - You should back up your database before using ACCESS platform reorder fields, for me It works without problems

Comment: If reordering fields permanently is your only reason for migrating from File to Personal Geodatabases I would look at the [**Make Query Table technique**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32310/how-to-re-order-fields-permanently-using-arcgis-make-query-table-tool) for doing the reordering instead instead of moving to a generally more limited geodatabase type.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. It's not the only reason. another one is a the ability to use "DISTINCT" at Query Definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Updating definition queries in map documents after the workspace has been changed is all discussed in.....[the help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000004p000000)!

Comment: Your link does address some of the migration issues, however for definition query updates it shows how to go from PGDB to FGDB not FGDB to PGDB.  A bit more logic is involved when replacing double quotes with brackets.