# Altering order of attributes in table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table

I have gone through a sequence of table joins. The resultant table should be with the attributes rearranged in more logical order. I cannot find this functionality within ArcGIS or any mention of it in Python

For example, say a TableResultingFromJoins has the following attributes:

v1,v2,v3,w1,x1

... and I want it like this:

v1,w1,x1,v2,v3

What do I do?