# Alternatives to ArcGIS Diagrammer for Reordering Fields with ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 or higher

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, arcgis-diagrammer

I discovered that ArcGIS Diagrammer no longer supports ArcGIS Desktop beyond 10.3. This was the go-to tool for reordering fields for a feature class within a file geodatabase. I have subtypes applied, so I have to operate within the geodatabase environment.

Are there any suitable alternatives that would operate with ArcGIS Desktop (specifically ArcCatalog) **10.5 or higher**?

While my question is similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/reordering-fields-permanently-in-file-geodatabase-using-arcgis-desktop/33683#comment411862_33683) and others, most of those fixes are several years out-of-date, and apply to older versions of ArcGIS.

Comment: If any answers on the duplicate are still useful you should upvote them. If any are no longer useful you should downvote them. Asking the same question again simply because its answers are looking dated should not be done.